# Winforms Datagrid Crashing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I am trying to perform a search through all the rows of a datagrid that I have created through using a datatable. I loop through the rows and get the string needed for each row and I check to see if a second string I have is contained within the first or not. If it is not contained, then I set the row to visible = false. Unfortunately, the datagrid freezes then crashes almost immediately after starting.
Here's the relevant code:

```
private void OnTextboxNameChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = filterControl.stringName;
        for(int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.RowCount; x++)
        {
            if(DB.GetName(x).IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[x].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Oddly enough, if I were to change the "== -1" to "!= -1", it works perfectly except that it does the opposite of what I need it to do. It only crashes when it is not "!= -1".

Thanks for your time and help.

EDIT:
I have pinpointed the problem even further.
It crashes on the line where I set rows[x].visible but ONLY on the very first row or when x = 0. When I changed the string "name" to be something that does not include the very first row, it works perfectly.

What this means is that setting the very first row's visible property crashes the datagrid. My question is now, how can I get around that?

Comment: how about (db.......ordinalignorecase) <0 && db.......ordinalignorecase)>-2)

Comment: Nope. That did not work and it still froze then crashed. It was worth a shot.